# How to copy to clipboard w/o os api using lua and ffi

Tags: lua, copy, clipboard, paste, ffi

How do you copy a value or string in lua? I’ve only found alternatives for the regular microsoft os api. For my use I do not have access to the os api and instead have access to ffi and steam panorama.

If possible I would also know how to get a string from the current clipboard.

I have access to,

1. LuaJIT 2.0.5 (https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT)
2. FFI (https://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html)
3. bit (https://bitop.luajit.org/api.html)

   via neverlose (https://docs.neverlose.cc)

Comment: I don't see how you would get to the system clipboard without interfacing the system.  ffi allows you to call C code, but even in C you would need some API. you can probably run some external program or shell commands though

Comment: What is the "steam panorama"?  What set of API functions do you have access to?  Is it true that you can not invoke WinAPI function from user32.dll/kernel32.dll?

Comment: There is a function `CopyTextToClipboard` at the panorama docs page you linked to in the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most beautiful solution, but assuming you can run the powershell:

```
local pipe = io.popen("powershell get-clipboard", "r")
local clipboard = pipe:read("*a")
print("Clipboard: " .. clipboard)
pipe:close()
```

Comment: In macOS, use `pbpaste`.

Comment: [string "local pipe = io.popen("power..."]:1: attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 [string "local pipe = io.popen("power..."]:1: in main chunk--

Comment: your running Lua in some sandbox without Lua's standard io library. without further information on your environment we can't help you but I guess chances that you can do this at all are close to zero.

Comment: ive seen it done with getting a string from the clipboard.

Comment: I have access to,
 1. LuaJIT 2.0.5 (https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT)
 2. FFI (https://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html)
 3. bit (https://bitop.luajit.org/api.html)
 4. Steam Panorama API (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Panorama_API)

    via neverlose (https://docs.neverlose.cc)

Answer (score -1):

In conditions of Source Engine (in this case - csgo) hacks Lua api, you can create interface to vgui2.dll and ffi.cast to it's functions. Here is three snippets of code for neverlose - initialisation, getting and setting clipboard.

If you want - you can still port this code to other csgo cheats by replacing `Utils.CreateInterface` with the same function what is in your cheat's api documentation. For example, in gamesense it will be `client.create_interface`

```
-- initialisation (ffi, creating functions and interface)
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
  typedef int(__thiscall* get_clipboard_text_count)(void*);
  typedef void(__thiscall* get_clipboard_text)(void*, int, const char*, int);
  typedef void(__thiscall* set_clipboard_text)(void*, const char*, int);
]]

local VGUI_Systemdll =  Utils.CreateInterface("vgui2.dll", "VGUI_System010")
local VGUI_System = ffi.cast(ffi.typeof('void***'), VGUI_Systemdll)
local get_clipboard_text_count = ffi.cast( "get_clipboard_text_count", VGUI_System[ 0 ][ 7 ] )
local get_clipboard_text = ffi.cast( "get_clipboard_text", VGUI_System[ 0 ][ 11 ] )
local set_clipboard_text = ffi.cast( "set_clipboard_text", VGUI_System[ 0 ][ 9 ] )
```

```
-- getting clipboard content
local clipboard_text_length = get_clipboard_text_count( VGUI_System )
local clipboardstring = ""
if clipboard_text_length > 0 then -- game will probably crash without that check
  local buffer = ffi.new("char[?]", clipboard_text_length)
  local size = clipboard_text_length * ffi.sizeof("char[?]", clipboard_text_length)
  get_clipboard_text( VGUI_System, 0, buffer, size )
  clipboardstring = ffi.string( buffer, clipboard_text_length-1 )
end
-- clipboardstring variable is what's in the clipboard
```

```
-- writing to clipboard
local some_cool_string = "i love ryuko very much"
set_clipboard_text(VGUI_System, some_cool_string, some_cool_string:len())
```